# jQuery click mobile problems (slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have coded a small script for scrolling in a vertical gallery on mobile devices – in browser everything works fine, but I can't make it work on my smartphone. What am I doing wrong?

Thats my query:

```
jQuery( '.single-cinema-cat .next' ).on('click touchstart', function () {
    alert("The btn was clicked.");
    if( jQuery( this ).hasClass( 'disabled' ) )
        return;
    jQuery( this ).addClass( 'disabled' );

    var $el = jQuery( this );
    if( jQuery( window ).innerWidth() >= 970 )
        scrollVertical_next( $el );
    else
        scrollHorizontal_next( $el );
});
```

the click element is a span-element in my html markup – could this be a problem? screenshot of my markup: https://picload.org/image/ralwaarg/jquerymobile.png

please save me for further headaches :-)

***scrollVertical_next***

```
function scrollVertical_next($el) {
var $wrapper = $el.closest('.single-cinema-cat').find('.inner');
var margin = parseInt($wrapper.find('article').css('margin-bottom')) + parseInt($wrapper.find('article').css('margin-top'));
var current_height = parseInt($wrapper.find('ul').css('top'));
var single_height = $wrapper.find('article').outerHeight() + margin;
var target_height = current_height - single_height;
var total_height = $wrapper.find('ul').innerHeight();
var stopper_height = -1 * total_height + 4 * single_height;
if (target_height < stopper_height)
    return;
$wrapper.find('ul').animate({
    'top': target_height + 'px'
}, 250, 'swing', function() {
    if (target_height > stopper_height)
        $el.removeClass('disabled');
    $el.closest('.single-cinema-cat').find('.prev').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

}

***scrollHorizontal_next***

```
function scrollHorizontal_next($el) {
var $wrapper = $el.closest('.single-cinema-cat').find('.inner');
var margin = parseInt($wrapper.find('article').css('margin-bottom')) + parseInt($wrapper.find('article').css('margin-top'));
var current_height = parseInt($wrapper.find('ul').css('top'));
var single_height = $wrapper.find('article').outerHeight() + margin;
var target_height = current_height - single_height;

var total_height = $wrapper.find('ul').innerHeight();
var stopper_height = -1 * total_height + 1 * single_height;
if (target_height < stopper_height)
    return;

$wrapper.find('ul').animate({
    'top': target_height + 'px'
}, 250, 'swing', function() {
    if (target_height > stopper_height)
        $el.removeClass('disabled');
    $el.closest('.single-cinema-cat').find('.prev').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Touch event must be handled this way

```
jQuery('.single-cinema-cat .next').on('click touchstart', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.handled !== true) {

    ////////// your stuff //////////////////////////


            alert("The btn was clicked.");
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('disabled'))
                return;
            jQuery(this).addClass('disabled');

            var $el = jQuery(this);
            if (jQuery(window).innerWidth() >= 970)
                scrollVertical_next($el);
            else
                scrollHorizontal_next($el);

   //////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

            event.handled = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help! the alert is triggered on my iphone but it still doesnt work that the slider switches the image... on desktop everything is still fine

Comment: Could you share your `scrollHorizontal_next` Function please ?

Comment: When you say it's working on desktop, do you mean, by simulating a phone resolution and emulating touch events ?
If you still can't find the solution, you can debug your phone using this :
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/
See if there are some errors, or putting some breakpoints to see what's going on